# Isolate current flow in Ltspice using switch

Tags: ltspice, isolation, constant-current, analog-switch

[image: Figure 1]

I am trying to control the flow of current by the switch SW, I have used an independent current source I. However the switch is ineffective to isolate the resistor R1, because the switch is basically an automatic resistor whose resistance toggles between Ron and Roff. Since I am using a constant current source, it doesn't matter what series resistance is in the path, the current flows, thus making the switch ineffective in stopping the current.

How can I stop or isolate the resistor using a switch?
In the response graph I expect the RED and BLUE to follow the GREEN.

Ps. I already tried the controlled current source, it works but I cannot use that in my circuitry because I only want to isolate a small part of the circuit (like R1) from the main circuit.

Comment: The current source, when operating open circuit, has infinite voltage across its terminals. That's why you don't see what you expect. Do you have to use an ideal current source? Did you try with a voltage source or can you replace the current source with one closest to your actual circuit implementation?

Comment: Your circuit is not realistic.  The current source needs a parallel resistance.  LTspice is actually detecting this problem behind the scenes and automatically adding a 1teraohm parallel resistor in order to make the simulation run (otherwise there will be a singular matrix error).  However, the 1gigaohm of the switch swamps it out.  Therefore, you need this additional parallel resistance to be less than 1gigaohm.  Try `1meg`, like the answer posted suggests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change to a voltage source.

Finish your circuit and other elements may take the current instead.  Even a 1Meg resistor in parallel with the current source will solve the problem in this specific example (since your Roff is 1G).